# Multiple Spawn/expect issue

Tags: tcl, expect

Currently, I am working on a script to automatize a Data Collector process. Through a long term run i have split these Collector script into four pieces. Now I want to start these Collectorscripts simultan, but i dont know how to do this. my Code ist working a bit:

```
package require Expect
log_user 0
set timeout 10200

spawn ./Log.tcl 2 5 1; set spawn1 $spawn_id
spawn ./Log.tcl 3 4 2; set spawn2 $spawn_id
spawn ./Log.tcl 7 8 2; set spawn3 $spawn_id
spawn ./Log.tcl 6 9 3; set spawn4 $spawn_id
expect -i $spawn1 eof {wait ; puts "--- 2,5 fertig ---"}
expect -i $spawn2 eof {wait ; puts "--- 3,4 fertig ---"}
expect -i $spawn3 eof {wait ; puts "--- 7,8 fertig ---"}
expect -i $spawn4 eof {puts "--- 6,9 fertig ---"}
```

this is run and made the thing. But if one job is ready before the other it will produces zombies. Is there a possibility to made this easy and beautiful? I have try a few thinks with exp_after, exp_background, $any_spawn_id with a while loop. But nothing worked. expect never get eof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to know the order in which the spawned commands finished, it is difficult to do with wait, but `expect` will accept a list of spawn ids to listen to simultaneously. For example,

```
spawn sleep 2
 lappend allids $spawn_id
 set cmd($spawn_id) "sleep 2"
spawn sleep 1
 lappend allids $spawn_id
 set cmd($spawn_id) "sleep 1"

while { [llength $allids]>0 } {
 expect -i "$allids" eof {
  puts "eof on $expect_out(spawn_id) from cmd $cmd($expect_out(spawn_id))"
  set idx [lsearch -exact $allids $expect_out(spawn_id)]
  set allids [lreplace $allids $idx $idx]
 }
}
```

This runs 2 commands, `sleep 2` and `sleep 1`, and appends each spawn id into the list `allids`. For convenience, the command is also noted in the array `cmd` indexed by the spawn id of that command.

The list of all spawn ids is then given to `expect eof` using `-i`.
When an eof is matched, the global variable `$expect_out(spawn_id)` contains the spawn id of the process causing the match. A message is printed after indexing this value in the `cmd` array.

Finally, the spawn id with eof is removed from the list, and the loop repeated until the list is empty.

Note, you cannot use `exp_continue` to continue the expect loop, as the `-i` value does not seem to be re-evaluated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code is work well. The most important was your note. I dont know before that the spawn wasnt evaluated by exp_continue